# I am having problems getting an image to sit right on top of a block for some reason

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

**MY PROBLEM**

I want the 2 ribbonpurplefade.gif's to be RIGHT up again the navmenu bar block that I colored pink (I made it an ugly pink so I can see the boundaries of the blocks).

***The top ribbonpurplefade.gif should be sitting RIGHT on top of the navmenu with NO GAPS between them.  The bottom ribbonpurplefade.gif should be snug against the bottom of the navmenu with NO GAPS between them.***

***Nothing I do gets rid of the gaps!  That's my problem! :)***

I put colors around everything so I can visually see where the blocks are.  If you know what I did wrong - please let me know :)  And yes, the colors are really ugly - it's so I can see the blocks :)  Thanks in advance!

*If you don't know what blocks are check out w3.org - they use the term liberally describing anonymous blocks, and `<div>This is a block</div>` `<p>This is also a block</p>` etc...*

**WHAT I TRIED**

I have tried 0px for margin and padding and on the img tag.  ONly thing that seems to work is using negative values but I don't understand why that would be...  I seemed to be able to get them to line up using the ribbonpurplefade.gif as background images but then I could not stretch them in the CSS.  So, I changed from using a background image to using an image as you see below and have been trying to make them touch the navmenu.

What I want is the 2 ribbonpurplefade.gif's to be snug up against the navmenu block.  Why this isn't working is beyond me.  I even tried a reset CSS file and it still does it.  Maybe it's not possible.  I even tried hspace and vspace but they are depreciated now anyways.

***Any solutions need to work with IE7 and up (and alternate browsers FF, Chrome, Op)***

**HTML**

```
<div class="navribbon"><img src="graphics/common/ribbonpurplefade.gif"></div>
<!-- THIS IS WHERE THE TOP GAP IS. I CANT GET RID OF IT COMPLETELY -->
<!-- NAVIGATION BAR HERE -->
<div class="navmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services & Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Online Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support & Drivers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Company Information</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- NAVIGATION ENDED -->
<!-- THIS IS WHERE THE BOTTOM GAP IS. I CANT GET RID OF IT COMPLETELY -->
<div class="navribbon"><img src="graphics/common/ribbonpurplefade.gif"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* NAVIGATION RIBBONS BELOW */
.navribbon {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    /*background-color:#129933;*/
}

.navribbon img {
    padding:2px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#00FF66;
}

/* NAVIGATION CSS BELOW*/
.navmenu {
    text-align:center;
    padding:9px;
    margin:0px;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color: #FF0066;
    border:dotted;
}

.navmenu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.navmenu li {
    display:inline;
    font-weight:bold;
    /*background-color: #99FF99;*/
}

.navmenu ul a {
    text-decoration:none;
    /*color:#4E4E4E;*/
    /*color: #276056;*/
    color:#267CB2;
}

.navmenu a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:black;
}

.navmenu li:after {
    content: "\\";
    padding: 0px 5px;
    color: #999;
}

.navmenu li:last-child:after {
    content: none;
}
```

**UPDATE: May 22, 2012**

Well, I tried using tables and putting the top image centered DOWN and the bottom image centered UP but it still puts a gap there.  I guess my only solution left is to create a DIV block and absolutely position the elements inside the div or redo all those ribbons in photoshop, resize them all, and resave them back.  Ugh... so much work for something SO simple.  I just don't understand WHY there is a gap when on every element I say - 0px for margin, padding - I mean... do we not have control over where stuff goes?  Why does it HAVE to be a background to line up snugly against another block element?  Stupid web design really ticks me off.  Almost feel like making everything absolute.  ARGH!

Comment: it will be much easier if  you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code

Comment: I did create a fiddle account (didn't know that existed) - stuck some code in but it was kinda messy due to the mixed php and html.  I removed the php - then my images wouldn't load in.  I'll play with fiddle another day now that I know it exists.  In the meantime I left my website in the same state as the code I pasted in here.  I know you can modify code in the browsers - just need someone to point out my mistake.  I WILL check into fiddle more in the future now that I know about it (thx) - currently its 3am - I have to get to bed.  Work tomorrow.  :)

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What image do you want to sit where? What blocks? And what's up with the purple bars?? Please describe what exactly you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hi there.  My problem is... there is a gap between the 2 seperators and the navigation list.  I can't get the top ribbonpurplefade.gif to sit RIGHT on top of the navmenu (the entire block).  The bottom ribbonpurplefade.gif should be snug against the bottom of the navmenu.  When I talk about blocks... a block is <div>This is a block</div> <p>This is also a block</p> - the entire navmenu block i colored pink so I can see it's dimensions.  The 2 images need to not have ANY space between them and the navmenu.  I dont want a gap between them.  Thats all :)

Comment: I re-worded my question above in the main code, removed some "not really needed code"... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured this one out after an hour of banging my head against a brick wall. The `img` tag is an `inline` element by default, so it has a minimum height which is dictated by the prevailing `font-size` wherever it's placed. This means that regardless of what height you give it below that minimum, it will always want to make room for the text which may surround it. That's why there's always what appears to be some margins or padding above and below it.

The solution to your problem is to make your `img` tags `display:block`.

Comment: You are correct!  I did a jsfiddle on a newer question and they answered it already BUT you answered it here!   display: block on the img tag does solve the problem!  Thank you SO much!  Your answer is correct!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the 2 purple fade bar's right? If that's the case: You forgot to add width="100%" in the lower bar.

Thus its much better to do the following in css:

```
.navribbon
{
background-image: url('../graphics/common/ribbonpurplefade.gif'); <-- Check path to be sure
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height: 11px;
width: 100%;
}
```

If you pick the CSS solution.. then remove the `<img>` inside your div.

Comment: Hi there, I know there is a discrepancy between the 2 ribbons.  I was trying different things.  I originally had it as a css rule as a background but since you can't stretch them with CSS I chose to include them via <img src=.... width="100%"> etc.  My last comment on the person above you explains exactly what I was trying to do and why it doesnt work.  Thx for this but it's not workable this way unless I RE-create the images in photoshop since I can't stretch them in CSS and I don't wish for them to be repeated either vertically or horizontally.

Comment: I re-worded my question above in the main code, removed some "not really needed code"... :)

Answer (score 0):

in my understand you have a problem to with both ribbon image width

```
<img src="graphics/common/ribbonpurplefade.gif" alt="ribbon" width="100%" border="1">
```

use this i have change in second image width="100%" if you have any other issue then please use 
http://jsfiddle.net/

Thanks.

Comment: Hi there.  That wasn't the problem I was having.  I was trying to get the ribbonpurplefade.gif to be right up against the navmenu block with no spaces between them.  The 2 ribbonpurplefade.gif's are different because I was changing one of them to try different things.